# How do I get elements navigating through tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** data from a webpage. It has a table that the same data is displayed through 3 views using 3 links.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="tab-curso" title="">Por curso</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="tab-localidade" title="">Por localidade</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="tab-ead" title="">Educação a distancia</a>
```

The code

```
For Each l In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If l.Href = "javascript:void(0);" Then
        l.Click
    End If
Next
```

It is extracting the data from the 3rd link (`<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="tab-ead" title="">Educação a distancia</a>`).

How do I extract from the second link? (`<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="tab-localidade" title="">Por localidade</a>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
For Each l In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If l.Title= "Educação a distancia" Then l.Click
Next
```